# Regex MatchCollection gets too many results

Tags: c#, regex

Using C# and Regex I have a strange situation:

```
string substr = "9074552545,9075420530,9075662235,9075662236,9075952311,9076246645";
MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(substr, @"[\d]*");
```

In my world the above would give me a result in 'collection' that contains 6 results. Strangly enough my collection contains 12 results and every second result is {} (empty).

I have tried rewriting it to:

```
string substr = "9074552545,9075420530,9075662235,9075662236,9075952311,9076246645";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\d]*");
MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(substr);
```

But it gives me the exact same result. What am I missing here?

I am using .Net framework 4.5, C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the problem is your `*` quantifier. It matches zero or more characters, which means an empty string is technically a match. You need to use the `+` quantifier, like this:

```
string substr = "9074552545,9075420530,9075662235,9075662236,9075952311,9076246645";
MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(substr, @"\d+");

// or
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
MatchCollection collection = regex.Matches(substr);
```

It will ensure that only strings with one or more digits are returned.

Note, I've also dropped the character class (`[]`) around your `\d` as it's completely unnecessary here.

**Further Reading:**

- [Quantifiers in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for regex:

```
string[] results = substr.Split(',');
```